# Usar um token em um formulário HTML realmente protege contra CSRF?

Tags: http, formulário, csrf

> Cross-site request forgery - **O CSRF** (do inglês Cross-site request forgery- Falsificação de solicitação entre sites) é um tipo de exploração maliciosa de um website pelo qual comandos não autorizados são transmitidos de um usuário que confia no website. Ao contrário do cross-site scripting (XSS), que explora a confiança de um usuário para um site particular, o CSRF explora a confiança que um site tem do navegador do usuário.

[Referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/csrf/info)

Acabei de fazer a pergunta falando a respeito de utilização de `token` em um `input hidden` de um formulário para evitar o `CSRF - Cross-Site Request Forgery`; e me surgiu uma dúvida.

Mesmo usando `tokens` em formulários de login e afins, ainda assim, é possível forjar uma requisição?

Existem outros meios, além do csrf token, de se proteger contra esse tipo de ataque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizar [*tokens*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_%28chave_eletr%C3%B4nica%29) somente faz a prevenção, não há uma garantia real de proteção.

Esse ataque pode ser prevenido de vários modos. Usando [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) é uma maneira que a aplicação pode contar com a [política de mesma origem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem) para evitar [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29), mantendo uma chave secreta para autenticar pedidos.

Ao adotar o [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) você assegura que cada pedido requer, em adição ao *cookie* de sessão um *token* gerado aleatoriamente como um parâmetro HTTP.

A cada pedido que for submetido a aplicação deverá procurar o valor esperado para o parâmetro e compará-lo com o valor real do pedido, se os valores não coincidirem, o pedido deve ser abortado e se possível redefinir o *token* e registrar esse evento como um potencial ataque.

Isso pode ser feito com segurança desde a [política de mesma origem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem) garanta que o site mal-intencionado não leia a resposta. A maioria dos navegadores atuais implementa essa política, portanto podemos acreditar que essa solução seja adequada para esse tipo de ataque.

[**Aqui**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) mostra algumas soluções que *não* devem ser adotadas e mostra alternativas que podem ser usadas sem o *Synchronizer Token Pattern*.